# Exporting code module from an Add-In into Normal template

Tags: vba, ms-word, office-2016

I want to export a VBA module from an Add-in and import it into Normal if it is not already there. My code works when I run it manually, but when I try to run automatically after the Add-in loads, I get the error: "50289 Can't perform operation since project is protected". I assume this is protected because it is loaded as an add-in, but is there any way around this?

```
 Sub AutoExec()
    Call MoveAutoMacro
 End Sub

 Function MoveAutoMacro()

    Dim sPath, thisName As String
    Dim moduleCount, i As Integer
    Dim amExists As Boolean

    moduleCount = Application.Templates("Normal.dotm").VBProject.vbcomponents.Count
    amExists = False
    For i = 1 To moduleCount
           thisName = Application.Templates("Normal.dotm").VBProject.vbcomponents(i).Name
        If thisName = "AutoMacros" Then amExists = True
    Next

    If Not amExists Then
        sPath = Environ("USERPROFILE") & Application.PathSeparator & "Desktop" & Application.PathSeparator & _
            "AutoMacros.bas"
        ThisDocument.VBProject.vbcomponents("AutoMacros").Export sPath
        Application.Templates("Normal.dotm").VBProject.vbcomponents.Import sPath
    End If
End Function
```

Comment: Your assumption is correct. Why do they need to be in Normal.dotm?  If you put them in a different add-in, you can put this code in Normal and just unload the one you're altering before you start.

Comment: @Comintern The module includes AutoOpen() and AutoNew() routines that I need to be run on any document that gets opened, so it needs to live in Normal. I can have it loaded manually by IT into Normal, but I wanted to do a check from this Add-in in case somehow their Normal got replaced and they lost the macros.